# Iphone Text Display Issue

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I have a very simplified version a website that just displays text for users to view and sort through. However some of the text is randomly not displaying on an iphone. What is even more odd is that if I long press on the cell on an iphone it pops up with the number to try and complete a call.... Any ideas what is going on? It's fine on a web browser and fine on android.

Pictures attached for examples of errors. The url is http://jacobyfeed.com/mobile/ft-worth-steer-weight-breaks.html

Comment: Android - http://encorevisions.com/android.png
Iphone - http://encorevisions.com/iphone.png